# Get values from 3 tables into a summarized table SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've tried other solutions I've found here but I don't get the correct information back.

I have a table with many different records. A list of names with a status of active. Then I have another table which holds information for each name with a ticket number and then an assignment 'Assigned' and 'Feedback'. Not all names have a ticket.

Then 1 more table that holds a number of hours that goes towards that ticket number.

I want a summary of this information for each name whether there is info there or not. So I started with a subquery here is what I have.

```
select z.name as 'Name', round(coalesce(sum(x.Hours),0),2) as "Assigned", 
round(coalesce(sum(y.Hours),0),2) as "Feedback" from 
        (select name from namelist where status = 'Active') as z 
    left join
       (select e.realname as "Name", b.id as "Ticket", b.status as "Status", c.value - 
       COALESCE(sum(a.Hours),0) as "Hours" from user_table e
       join ticket_table b ON b.handler_id = e.id
       join custom_table c ON c.bug_id = b.id AND c.field_id = 7 
       left custom_table d ON d.bug_id = b.id AND d.field_id = 15
       left hours_table a ON a.Ticket = b.id
       where (b.status = 50)
       Group By b.id  
       ORDER BY `Name` ASC, `Status` DESC) x on z.Name= x.Name
    left JOIN
       (select e.realname as "Name", b.id as "Ticket", b.status as "Status", c.value - 
       COALESCE(sum(a.Hours),0) as "Hours" from user_table e
       join ticket_table b ON b.handler_id = e.id
       join custom_table c ON c.bug_id = b.id AND c.field_id = 7 
       left custom_table d ON d.bug_id = b.id AND d.field_id = 15
       left hours_table a ON a.Ticket = b.id
       where (b.status = 20)
       Group By b.id  
       ORDER BY `Name` ASC, `Status` DESC) y on z.Name= y.Name

   Group by Name
```

I've changed some of the names around but this is the basic idea. b.status = 50 means Assigned, and 20 means Feedback. Those joins create a table that looks like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Name | Ticket | Status| Hours ((value from custom_table)-(sum from hours table based on ticket))|
| Joe  |  234   | 50    |  20                                                                     |
| Joe  |  235   | 50    |  30                                                                     |
| Joe  |  236   | 50    |  40                                                                     |
| John |  233   | 50    |  10                                                                     |
| John |  237   | 50    |  20                                                                     |
| John |  238   | 50    |  20                                                                     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Name | Ticket | Status| Hours ((value from custom_table)-(sum from hours table based on ticket))|
| Joe  |  134   | 20    |  60                                                                     |
| Joe  |  135   | 20    |  30                                                                     |
| Joe  |  136   | 20    |  40                                                                     |
| John |  133   | 20    |  70                                                                     |
| John |  137   | 20    |  20                                                                     |
| John |  138   | 20    |  20                                                                     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-----------------
| Name | Status |
| Joe  |  Active| 
| John |  Active|
| Mary |  Active| 
| Tom  |  Active| 
| John |Inactive|
-----------------
```

Desired result:

```
----------------------------
| Name | Assigned| Feedback| 
| Joe  |  90     |   130   |  
| John |  50     |   110   | 
| Mary |  0      |    0    | 
| Tom  |  0      |    0    |
----------------------------
```

Now the Hours table is c.value which is a 1 to 1 relation subtract sum(hours) from hours table 1 to many relationship.

If I take out one of the joins, the table works. When I put them together like this, the numbers are incorrect. I can get the assigned correct if I only use that join. I can get the feedback numbers correct if I only use the feeback join. However it doesn't work when trying to get either from them. Let me know if you need more info I'll try my best to provide.

Example results:

```
----------------------------
| Name | Assigned| Feedback| 
| Joe  |  392    |   145   |  
| John |  125    |   94    | 
| Mary |  0      |    0    | 
| Tom  |  0      |    0    |
----------------------------

If I just use the table with status 50.
----------------------------
| Name | Assigned|  
| Joe  |  90     |   
| John |  50     | 
| Mary |  0      | 
| Tom  |  0      |
----------------------------

If I just use the table with status 20.
----------------------------
| Name | Assigned|  
| Joe  |  130    |   
| John |  110    | 
| Mary |  0      | 
| Tom  |  0      |
----------------------------
```

Don't worry about the custom tables so much, there is a reason they are there but aren't a part of my question. The biggest thing is simply getting the c.value from there, the other join to that table is only for another status, but not relevant to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Is this for MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: It goes through siteground so MySQL I believe.

Answer (score 0):

The two Left Joins seem identical to me apart from the status (unless I am missing something)

Have you tried using a single left join and then an aggregation with a Case statement i.e.

```
SELECT Name, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 50 THEN Hours ELSE 0 END) AS Assigned, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 20 THEN Hours ELSE 0 END) AS Feedback 

FROM table 

GROUP BY Name
```

I appreciate the answer here is over-simplified but it's more a suggestions since I don't know the content of all the tables mentioned in the query

SQL FIDDLE Example (apologies using SQL SERVER but logic in MySQL is the same for this simple example)
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f77e4/5/0

The output matches the desired results but the issue might lie with another table.
This assumes a single table but the logic should work the same using a left join

Comment: Hello thank you for your response. I did try that. But I then get a value in one column or the other. So I get a 0 in assigned because there is data in feedback. Because it's not Hours, I"m trying to sum the hours, so if I use else 0, the records that aren't status 50 puts that column as 0 rather than add to the total.

Comment: you can normally use MAX() in combination with it and it will make the columns display next to each other 
I will try to make an example for it in SQL Fiddle